# 404 Not Found when setting a path for Google cloud API Endpoint

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm defining a Google-Cloud endpoint like this:

```
@ApiMethod(
        name = "listcontacts",
        path = "contacts/myUser",
        httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET)
public CollectionResponse<myUser> listContacts(@Named("phones")String[] phones) {
```

The compilation and upload to Google Cloud is successful but whenever i try to call this endpoint from the client-side. I get a 404 not found:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
```

However, if i set the path to just "myUser" it will work correctly. The problem is that it clashes with another api method with the same path.

Comment: Hi @dustedrob,
having the same issue here. So far it looks like an gapi client issue to me.
Can you please confirm that
a) you are using gapi client
b) this happens for devserver and deployed app
c) what version of AppEngine SDK are you using?
Try calling the api url without gapi client. If your ApiMethod path is /myapi/something call yourdomain/_ah/api/yourapi/v1/myapi/something